# CSS clickb-able box that links to another page

Tags: php, html, css

I have been creating a website in HTML5, PHP, SQL and now CSS. as you can guess it is quite basic but im now trying to do the last part and get the UI working. I was wondering how i can create a Box in the top left of the screen that has the words "admin login" and when ANYWHERE in the box is clicked it links me to a new page (the admin login page). My basic problem is that I really dont get on with CSS well. If anyone has any tips that would be great. this is what i have so far. 
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLXb.png) The Problem with this is that you can still only click on the words "admin login not the entire region.

```
<h5 style = "text-align:center;display:inline-block;width:100px;height:35px;background-color:#ccc;border:1px solid #ff0000;"> <a href = "http://127.0.0.1/loginscreen_ui.html">Admin Login </a> </h5>
```

Yours Sincerely
Gsg

Comment: `<a href="admin-url"><h5>ADMIN LOGIN</h5></a>` Tada

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href = "http://127.0.0.1/loginscreen_ui.html">
   <h5 style = "text-align:center;display:inline-block;width:100px;height:35px;background-color:#ccc;border:1px solid #ff0000;">Admin Login </h5>
</a>
```